# How to set a Horizontal Line on Page Break in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with pdf like this in jaspersoft studio
[image]

Here you can clearly see I need a horizontal line on page break, But I do not know how to achieve that, I have used `column header` for horizontal line for the Top of each page of the table, but for the bottom line for page break, I am not finding any solution. I am using jaspersoft studio version 6.20.5

This is my detail band code for reference

```
<detail>
        <band height="50" splitType="Immediate">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="537" height="50" uuid="bd5ab1bb-9abb-42eb-b01f-71347bce6825">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <line>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="23" y="0" width="1" height="50" uuid="175bec98-0a73-4f21-abd9-9fccc4fd5d5f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                </line>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="3" width="20" height="47" uuid="6a6e737e-701d-4151-a281-ea0062ce558c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}+"."]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="29" y="0" width="501" height="50" uuid="220d14f8-7cee-4315-9cf7-647b7c480735"/>
                    <textElement markup="styled"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Any help is appreciated.